# LAMMPS for GPU error - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_stubs while making using make command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, lammps

I am trying to install LAMMPS in gpu. After following the steps given in http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/accelerate_gpu.html, I have finished step (a) and got the files - libgpu.a and Makefile.lammps.

When I try to proceed with the second step(make serial after make yes-gpu), I get an error saying - `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_stubs`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the linker is unable to find the MPI library necessary to build. Typically, `make serial` builds lammps without MPI support. From `make help` (called in the `lammps/src` directory):

```
# serial = RedHat Linux box, g++4, no MPI, no FFTs
```

However, the Lammps GPU package requires MPI. Thus,

1. Make sure you have the necessary MPI libraries installed.
2. Build lammps with one of the following commands (see `make help` for more options):

   1. `make g++` (Compiler: g++4, MPI implementation: MPICH2)
   2. `make g++3` (Compiler: g++3, MPI implementation: MPICH2)
   3. `make linux` (Compiler: icc, MPI implementation: MPICH2)
   4. `make openmpi` (Compiler: mpic++, MPI implementation: OpenMPI-1.1)